# Area of surface

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

What is the area of the region that is bounded by the curve $$\vec{R}(t)=(\cos^3t, \sin^3t), 0\leq t<2\pi?$$
I have no idea how to start here or what i have to use.

Comment: By chance, have you recently learned Green's theorem?

Comment: Yes, how do i use it here?

Comment: By surface do you mean the region in the plane?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yes, i think so

Comment: This http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_Calculation should be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The curve is given by
$$x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$$
The graph of the curve looks like below.[image]

Hence, the area of the graph is
$$A = 4 \int_0^1 \left(1-x^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}dx$$
Setting $x=\sin^3(t)$, we obtain $dx=3\sin^2(t)\cos(t) dt$. Hence, we have the area to be
\begin{align}
A & = 4 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^3(t)\cdot 3\sin^2(t)\cos(t) dt = 12 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^4(t)(1-\cos^2(t))dt\\
& = 12 \left(\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^4(t) dt - \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^6(t) dt\right)
\end{align}
[From here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5de5tfewssffmgk/Integrate_power_of_sine_from_0_to_pi_over2.pdf?dl=0), we have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2m}(t)dt = \dfrac{\pi}{2^{2m+1}} \dbinom{2m}m$$
Hence, we obtain that the area is
$$A = 12\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^5} \dbinom{4}2 - \dfrac{\pi}{2^7} \dbinom{6}3\right) = 3\pi \left(\dfrac68 - \dfrac{20}{32}\right) = \dfrac{3\pi}8$$